# sudo apt autoremove wants to remove a lot of packages, safe to run?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Following on from a **reinstall of ubuntu desktop** `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to fix a previous issue with not booting.

and then a reinstall of google chrome

`sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable`

I got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'google-chrome-stable' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common gnome-panel-data gnome-shell-pomodoro-data gparted-common intltool
  libaacs0 libaom0 libaribb24-0 libass9 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libcodec2-0.9 libegl1-mesa libflite1
  libgconf-2-4 libgme0 libgsm1 liblilv-0-0 libmusicbrainz5-2 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libmysofa1 libnorm1 libnuma1 libopenmpt0
  libpaps0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc55 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib librubberband2 libserd-0-0
  libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libx265-179 libxcb-xtest0 libxnvctrl0 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  mesa-vdpau-drivers paps python-gobject-2 python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3-distutils-extra
  python3-levenshtein python3-pyinotify python3-websocket vdpau-driver-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.
```

And running `sudo apt autoremove` gives a warning about removing these packages

> The following packages will be REMOVED ...

And the list of packages again. My question is is this safe to run, are these packages neccessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running `sudo apt-get autoremove` run `sudo apt-get -y update --fix-missing` and upgrade using "Software & Updates" or `sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

Recently I installed some new softwares and removed some software which I found unnecessary. After that when ever I ran sudo apt-get command in terminal it shows me a huge list of dependencies/ software marked as no more required. When I ran `sudo apt-get -y upgrade` the list reduced to a small list.

Comment: *a hug list*? Or *a huge list*? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of **autoremove** says

```
autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed
```

Therefore, no issue in running **autoremove** at all. I have done it so many times in past and never get into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If autoremove proposes to remove them, then it's safe to run, they are not needed by any other packages.

However, you could just copy-paste the list just in case something goes wrong. Like that, you can re-install them again.